# Passing scalar parameter to be evaluated in IF cycle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

In one of my methods, I need to provide an optional parameter of type UIEdgeInsets. The implementation of the method contains an IF condition that should test whether some insets were provided at all.
How should I test in the IF condition, whether insets were provided?

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant code.

Comment: Why, is my description lacking clarity? The problem is trivial, anybody can imagine a method that takes in UIEdgeInsets, and then inside the method an IF cycle with condition that checks that argument for being either nil, or not nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIEdgeInsets` are a `struct`, not an object pointer. That means it will never be `nil`.
There can't be a case when the caller doesn't pass them. If he doesn't want to use insets, he can always pass `UIEdgeInsetsZero`.

If you want to have a method where no insets are passed, just create a second one without that parameter.

Comment: But when I do this 
-->
if (paramEdgeInsets == UIEdgeInsetsZero)
-->
the debugger complains....

Comment: @EarlGrey Is there a need to check it? Can't you just use the zeros in the same way you would use real values? Anyway, structs cannot be compared by ==, you have to compare their components. Or use a function `UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(insets, UIEdgeInsetsZero)`

Comment: Very nice function. I hoped exactly for something like this.

Comment: btw..you see what I needed, so I don't really understand why the question was closed. Instead of positively encourage users to perhaps rephrase the question, add value to it, mods here are playing gods on questionable grounds...

Comment: @EarlGrey the question was phrased really poorly. You need a lot of imagination to answer it. In general, questions are supposed to include "what have you tried" code. It also shows poor understanding of obj-c programming and terminology in general so it won't probably help any future visitors.

Comment: @EarlGrey use `UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets()` for comparisons